# bash How to escape specialcharacter '@' in filename template?

Tags: bash, templates, filenames

How to escape specialcharacter `@` in search filename template?

this code doesn't work (empty result)

```
for file in *_@2.png; do echo "$file"; done
```

also tried this:

```
for i in *_@2.png; do mv "$i" "${i/_@2.png}"@2x.png; done
```

I need to rename files `*_@2.png` to `*@2x.png`

Comment: use backslash fo escaping

Comment: it doesn't works too for file in *\@2.png; do echo "$file"; done
I get *\@2.png

Comment: or use single quotes

Comment: and `\@2.png; do echo "$file"; done I get \@2.png`?

Comment: works only for file in *.png; do echo "$file"; done

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? As in what is the exact behavior or error.

Comment: empty list of files

Comment: Is there any output from `printf '%s\n' *_@2.png`? If not, then you don't have any files that end in `_@2.png`. I don't think that you need to escape `@` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file exists

```
for file in *_@2.png; do
    [[ -e $file ]] || continue  # to skip file which not exists
    ...
done
```

Using shell options.
If failglob option is not set when not glob match the glob `*_@2.png` expand to itself

```
shopt globfail     # to check value
shopt -s globfail  # to turn on
shopt -u globfail  # to turn off
```

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
for i in *.png; do mv "$i" "${i/_@2.png/@2x.png}" ; done
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.